# addressing data from increasing number of excel spreadsheet to the other excel file

Tags: excel

I have two excel files and want to address specific data from one excel file to others. I create new sheet every day and in this case, addresing cell data from increasing sheets face a problem.

Is there a way to address selected data from increasing number of excel spreadsheet to the other excel file without openning it?

Any comments or suggestion are appreciated